# Can i use a GCP HTTPS Load Balancer to route between a bucket backend and a Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

i wanted to understand what are my load balancing options in a scenario where i want to use a single HTTPS Load Balancer on GCP to serve some static content from a bucket and dynamic content using a combination of react front end and express backend on Kubernetes.

Additional info:

- i have a domain name registered outside of Google Domains
- I want to serve all content over https
- I'm not starting with anything big.  Just getting started with a more or less hobby type project which will attract very little traffic in the near future.
- I dont mind serving my react front end, express backend from app engine if that helps simplify this somehow.  however, in such a case, i would like to understand if i still want something on kubernetes, will i be able to communicate between app engine and kubernetes without hassles using internal IPs.  And how would i load balance that traffic!!

Any kind of network blueprint in the public domain that will guide me will be helpful.

I did quite a bit of reading on NodePort/LoadBalancer/Ingress which has left me confused.  from what i understand, LoadBalancer does not work with HTTP(S) traffic, operates more at TCP L4 Level, so probably not suitable for my use case.

Ingress provisions a dedicated Load Balancer of its own on which i cannot put my own routes to a backend bucket etc, which means i may need a minimum of two load balancers? and two IPs?

NodePort exposes a port on all nodes, which means i need to handle load balancing myself even if my HTTPS Load balancer routing can somehow help.

Any guidance/pointers will be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** Found some information on Network Endpoint Groups (NEG) while researching.  Looking promising.  will investigate.  Any thoughts about taking this route?  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg

**EDIT:** Was able to get this working using a combination of NEGs and Nginx reverse proxies.

Comment: attempting to set up a standalone NEG.  Running into issues.  have put up a followup question regarding that as it deviates from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143904/standalone-network-endpoint-group-neg-on-gke-not-working

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve your concerns please start with:

1. [Choosing the right loadbalncer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer):

   - Network load balancer (Layer 4 load balancing or proxy for applications that rely on TCP/SSL protocol) the load is forwarding  into your systems based on incoming IP protocol data, such as address, port, and protocol type.

     > The network load balancer is a **pass-through load balancer, so your backends receive the original client request**. The network load balancer doesn't do any Transport Layer Security (TLS) offloading or proxying. Traffic is directly routed to your VMs. 
     >   **Network loadbalancers terminatese TLS on backends** that are located in regions appropriate to your needs
   - HTTP(s) loadbalancer is a proxy-based, regional Layer 7 load balancer that enables you to run and scale your services behind a private load balancing IP address that is accessible only in the load balancer's region in your VPC network.

     > **HTTPS and SSL Proxy load balancers terminate TLS in locations that are distributed globally**.
     >   An HTTP(S) load balancer acts as a proxy between your clients and your application. If you want to accept HTTPS requests from your clients
     >   You have the option to use Google-managed SSL certificates (Beta) or to use certificates that you manage yourself.
     >
     > Technical Details
     >   When you create an Ingress object, the GKE Ingress controller configures a GCP **HTTP(S) load balancer** according to the rules in the Ingress manifest and the associated Service manifests. The client sends a request to the HTTP(S) load balancer. **The load balancer is an actual proxy**; it chooses a node and forwards the request to that node's NodeIP:NodePort combination. The node uses its iptables NAT table to choose a Pod. kube-proxy manages the iptables rules on the node. **Routes traffic is going to a healthy Pod for the Service specified in your rules**.
2. Per [buckets](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-bucket) documentation:

   > An HTTP(S) load balancer can direct traffic from specified URLs to either a backend bucket or a backend service.
   >   Bucket should be public while using Loadbalncer- Creating buckets  bucket
3. During LoaBalancer set-up you can choose backend service and backend bucket. You can find more information in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/adding-backend-buckets-to-load-balancers).

Please take a look also for this two tutorials [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine) how to build application using cloud storage.

Hope this help.

Additional resources:
[Loadbalancers, Controllers](https://blog.getambassador.io/kubernetes-ingress-nodeport-load-balancers-and-ingress-controllers-6e29f1c44f2d)

Comment: thank you for your valuable advice.  i am trying out a few options over the course of the week and will drop an update with my experience.

Comment: attempting to set up a standalone NEG.  Running into issues.  have put up a followup question regarding that as it deviates from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143904/standalone-network-endpoint-group-neg-on-gke-not-working